# Visual Studio - C# Console App - How to write a unit test and testable code

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm new to unit testing and would like to unit test part of my code.

The code attempts to connect to a database N times to get a list of tasks, if it exhausts the attempts it throws an exception to the caller.

I've done by best to write it in a testable way trying to keep AttemptRecursive referentially transparent.

I'd like to write tests that for example fail on the 1st/2nd attempt to check my code behaves correctly but I'm struggling to write the code in a way that will allow that as I can't stop in the middle of the recursive call in my Attempter class.

There seems to be a lot of differing opinions around the how & whys of unit tests so I'm not sure if I've just completely missed the point!

Essentially my thought is the database could go down and I'd like to test that when it happens my code behaves correctly.

I've read articles on unit testing - a lot of them are on what to test for and whether it's useful but not on how to write code that's open to testing. The examples are of functions like factorials where the tests are just if the returned list contains the expected values.

Any help or just pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

**Attempter.cs** - *Handles attempting an action N times then throwing exception to bubble up to the caller*

```
public class Attempter<T>
    {
        private int _defaultMaximumAttempts;
        private int _defaultStartingMillisecondsTillNextTry;

        public Attempter(int defaultMaximumAttempts, int defaultStartingMillisecondsTillNextTry)
        {
            _defaultMaximumAttempts = defaultMaximumAttempts;
            _defaultStartingMillisecondsTillNextTry = defaultStartingMillisecondsTillNextTry;
        }


        public void Attempt(T sender, Action action)
        {
            AttemptRecursive(
                sender: sender,
                action: action,
                attemptNumber: 1,
                maximumAttempts: _defaultMaximumAttempts,
                millisecondsTillNextTry: _defaultStartingMillisecondsTillNextTry);
        }


        public void AttemptRecursive(T sender, Action action, int attemptNumber, 
               int maximumAttempts, int millisecondsTillNextTry)
        {
            try
            {
                action.Invoke();
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if(attemptNumber >= maximumAttempts)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTillNextTry);
                    AttemptRecursive(sender, action, attemptNumber + 1, 
                         maximumAttempts, millisecondsTillNextTry * 2);
                }
            }
        }
```

**DatabaseService.cs** - *Uses the Attempter to attempt to connect to the database and run queries*

```
public class DatabaseService
    {
        private Attempter<DatabaseService> _attempter;

        public SqlConnectionStringBuilder ConnectionStringBuilder { get; set; }

        public DatabaseService(SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder)
        {
            ConnectionStringBuilder = connectionStringBuilder;
            _attempter = new Attempter<DatabaseService>(
                maximumAttempts: 1,
                startingMillisecondsTillNextTry: 1000);
        }

        public DatabaseService(SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder, 
             Attempter<DatabaseService> attempter)
        {
            ConnectionStringBuilder = connectionStringBuilder;
            _attempter = attempter;
        }

        public void AttemptExecuteNonQuery(string cmdText)
        {
            _attempter.Attempt(
                    sender: this,
                    action: () => ExecuteNonQuery(cmdText));
        }

        private void ExecuteNonQuery(string cmdText)
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();          
                //con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con))
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
                }
            }
        }

        public List<T> AttemptExecuteReader<T>(string cmdText, 
             Func<SqlDataReader, T> constructorFunction)
        {
            var returnList = new List<T>();
            _attempter.Attempt(
                    sender: this,
                    action: () => returnList = ExecuteReader<T>(cmdText, constructorFunction));
            return returnList;
        }

        private List<T> ExecuteReader<T>(string cmdText, Func<SqlDataReader,T> constructorFunction)
        {
            var returnList = new List<T>();
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con))
                {
                    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        returnList.Add(constructorFunction(reader));
                    }
                }
            }
            return returnList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have attempter being initialized in the DataService class. So it will work as per it's implementation even when you are running unit testing DataService. If you want to unit tests of DataService code it should not be affected by Attempter behavior. You need to have attempter as dependency to the DataService class so that you can mock it and decide it's behavior while unit testing DataService code.

Comment: A good book about how to write testable code is this one:  **Working Effectively with Legacy Code (Michael C. Feathers)** (https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/working-effectively-with/0131177052/) 
 Although the title says "Legacy Code", it's about transforming code so it can be brought under unit test.

Comment: Another topic very connected to testing is **Dependency Injection**. One of the goals of unit testing is to isolate just one thing and see if it works under varying circumstances. The way to do that is to make sure you control everything else, and the best way to do that is to inject proxies for the parts you need to control.